# the RecyclerView I am injecting does not appear?

Tags: android, xml, view, android-recyclerview, android-relativelayout

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:showIn="@layout/content_main">


        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:elevation="7dp">


            <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frame_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <include
                    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
                    layout="@layout/tool_bar"></include>
            </LinearLayout>


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="left"

                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:scrollbars="vertical">


            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/threadRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The main reason I did this design was to try to display the

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/threadRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

properly. However, when it is not being displayed at all. Before adding the two relativelayouts, I have one relative layout and the recyclerview did display, but it `match_parent` for every item of the list and was not able to fix it. How can I display my view properly?

Comment: Firstly update your question with proper explanation. Now, Try putting DrawerLayout as the parent Layout. Then implement it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem probably has to do with the `layout_height="wrap_content"` on your `RecyclerView`. You need to use `setAutoMeasureEnabled(true)` for `wrap_content` to work properly with a `RecyclerView`.
Here's an example:

```
RecyclerView threadRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.threadRecyclerView);
threadRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);
```

And your your XML should look something like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/threadRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" 
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"/>
```

Hope that helps. :)
Note that `setAutoMeasureEnabled` only works properly for [Android Support Library +23.2](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)